# How to read and write from MongoDb using two different drivers (MongoDB Scala Driver and Salat)

Tags: mongodb, scala, salat

We want to change our MongoDB driver overtime to MongoDB Scala Driver, but we using Salat and it reads and writes sealed classes and ADTs using "_typeHint" to the DB. The MongoDB Scala Driver reads and writes sealed classes and ADTs using "_t", What we want is a way to read and write "_typeHint" using MongoDB Scala Driver? We know we need a custom codec, but not sure how to implement it.

We want the ability to support both drivers until we remove Salat.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be described [here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.5/bson/pojos/). See "annotation convention" and "bson discriminator".

Comment: Thanks this looks promising, let me try it out. thanks for your answer